# How to transform MySQL query to Laravel Eloquent query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Here's the Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` as m
left join `tutor_segments` as ts on m.id = ts.tutor_id
left join subject_segments as seg on ts.segment_id = seg.id 
left join users_area as ua on ua.user_id=m.id
left join area as a on ua.area_id=a.id
where m.user_type=2 and (seg.segment_name like '%s%'
or a.area_name like '%s%'  or m.area like '%s%') 
group by m.id;
```

how to build a laravel query with query builder for this part `and (seg.segment_name like '%s%'
    or a.area_name like '%s%'  or m.area like '%s%')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write raw queries in laravel whereRaw()

```
$users = DB::table('users')
->leftJoin('tutor_segments', 'users.id', '=', 'tutor_segments.tutor_id')
->leftJoin('subject_segments', 'tutor_segments.segment_id', '=', 'subject_segments.id')
->leftJoin('users_area', 'users_area.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
->leftJoin('area', 'user_area.area_id', '=', 'area.id')
->whereRaw("users.user_type=2 and (subject_segments.segment_name like '%s%' or area.area_name like '%s%' or users.area like '%s%')")
->select('users.*')
->groupBy('users.id')
->get();
```

@Antony Thompson he need to select all data from users table so he need to use `->select('users.*')` instead of `->select('*')` and your query will generate error as you haven't created aliases for the selected tables.

Comment: this is simple and i used this one , thanks for your valuable time to help me

Comment: @user1912870 Good to know, I just cooked up something after reading the laravel docs. I'm just about to start my first project with laravel today actually :-) and loving it so far.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->leftJoin('tutor_segments', 'users.id', '=', 'tutor_segments.tutor_id')
    ->leftJoin('subject_segments', 'tutor_segments.segment_id', '=', 'subject_segments.id')
    ->leftJoin('users_area', 'users_area.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->leftJoin('area', 'user_area.area_id', '=', 'area.id')
    ->where('users.user_type', 2)
    ->where(function($query){
     $query->where('area.area_name', 'LIKE', '%s%')
        ->OrWhere('users.area_name', 'LIKE', '%s%')
        ->OrWhere('subject_segments.segment_name', 'LIKE','%s%');
     })       
    ->groupBy('users.id')
    ->get();
```

read the [doc](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#selects) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this? I havn't used laravel much at all but according to the docs thats how you do it.

```
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries
```

Code

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->leftJoin('tutor_segments', 'users.id', '=', 'tutor_segments.tutor_id')
    ->leftJoin('subject_segments', 'tutor_segments.segment_id', '=', 'subject_segments.id')
    ->leftJoin('users_area', 'users_area.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->leftJoin('area', 'user_area.area_id', '=', 'area.id')
    ->select('users.*')
    ->whereRaw(
        'users.user_type=2 and 
        (
            subject_segments.segment_name like ?
            or 
            area.area_name like ?  or users.area like ?
        )', array('%s%', '%s%', '%s%')
    )
    ->groupBy('users.id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: thank you  very much for your responce , will try this

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('users')
        ->leftJoin('tutor_segments', 'users.id', '=', 'tutor_segments.tutor_id')
        ->leftJoin('subject_segments', 'subject_segments.segment_id', '=', 'tutor_segments.tutor_id')
        ->leftJoin('users_area', 'users_area.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->leftJoin('area', 'area.id', '=', 'users_area.area_id')
        ->where('users.user_type', 2)
        ->where(function($query){
            $query->where('subject_segments.segment_name', 'LIKE', '%s%')
            ->orWhere('area.area_name', 'like', '%s%')
            ->orWhere('users.area', 'like', '%s%')
           })
        ->groupBy('users.id')
        ->get();
```

---